# I am using Maven structure selenium framework but I dont know how to integrate with Bamboo CI. Can any one help on this?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, continuous-integration

I am using Maven structure selenium framework but I dont know how to integrate with Bamboo CI. Can any one help on this? I am getting error even I built. Frustrating. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide further details. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add more info about the issue you have (for example, what is the error you get? what have you tried so far?)